# exponential value restriction in Float variable in C++

Tags: c++

I want my answer in some precision form but not for input output purposes.

`float a = cos ( 90*(PI/180))` `gives 1.794897E-09`

where as I want up to 8 decimal places answer in my variable which will give

`0.00000000`

setprecision or other methods are not helping to store the value in a variable. How can it be stored? basically it may not even be 8 or 9 digits .. all i want is restriction of an exponentiol form in my answer

Comment: Can you show a complete example? Right now it is not really clear where your problem lies ... the example line doesn't show I/O whereas `setprecision` isn't related to how something is stored. It might all be some confusion about the concept of floating point on your part as well ...

Answer (score 0):

You are limited by the type you are using. A single precision float can only represent between 6 and 9 significant decimal digits.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Remember, a float is not a decimal value. So what you're seeing is the decimal representation. If you want more digits in the decimal representation, use a double.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Double precision floats can represent values to 15-17 digits of decimal precision. This should guarantee the minimum of 8 that you require.

Answer (score 0):

The precision and encoding of floating point values is concretely defined by IEEE 754. Without defining your own implementation of of floating points should be stored in memory, you can't really change the internal precision for how it's encoded and stored in memory.

If you want better precision you can use **double**s. All the math functions work well  with doubles.